# authorization failed when i installed my app with installer.app on mac os lion

Tags: installation, authorization, applescript, osx-lion, packagemaker

I have a problem with my app to copy/delete a plist file in "/Library/LaunchAgents/" to control the auto-start function on checking/unchecking a checkbox.

I made an installer which has a "open file" action in "postinstall actions". After install, the app is started successfully, but when I check the checkbox and enter my admin password to enable "auto-start" for all the users, the auto start .plist file is not copied to /Library/LauchAgents/ .  If I kill the app then re-open the app manually, and then check the auto start option, the file can be copied to the folder successfully.

Here is the AppleScript i used for coping files to "/Library/LauchAgents/". I'm sure the sourcepath and the destinpath are right.

```
do shell script "cp '<sourcepath>' '<destinpath>'" with administrator privilege
```

Here are the error messages i got in Console:

```
9/30/11 11:12:18.217 AM authorizationhost: SFBuiltinEntitled: Installer.app is not entitled for system.install.app-store-software

9/30/11 11:12:18.219 AM com.apple.SecurityServer: Failed to authorize right 'system.install.app-store-software' by client '/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PackageKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/installd' [2042] for authorization created by '/System/Library/CoreServices/Installer.app' [2033]

9/30/11 11:12:18.277 AM installd: PackageKit: 
----- Begin install -----

9/30/11 11:12:19.977 AM MyAppDemo: awakeFromNib()

9/30/11 11:12:20.007 AM installd: Installed "My Application Package" ()

9/30/11 11:12:20.035 AM installd: PackageKit: 
----- End install -----
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct code is:

```
do shell script "cp '<sourcepath>' '<destinpath>'" with administrator privileges
```

Notice how privileges has an 's' on the end. Your script must be having errors when it's run because of the misspelling.